# Is there a way to copy from a Google Sheets that is copy locked?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

The owner of a Google Sheets can tick off the option: `"Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy"`.
However in this option, Google does not explicitly say that viewers cannot copy.

How are they able to copylock a spreadsheet and is there a way to bypass and copy anyway?

Here is a test spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DLeK4X4MFbQe6X6lcbE_O-rTdy3MHApZEu1HhUWIji4/edit#gid=0

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal from `How are they able to copylock a spreadsheet and is there a way to bypass and copy anyway?`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to directly copy the sheet, but there are a couple workarounds:

1. Copy cells values from the formula bar. (If the cell has a formula,
   it will copy the formula,not the actual value).
2. Copy values to another document using formula
   or Google Apps Script.

**Formula**

```
importrange("YOUR-ID","Sheet1!B2")
```

**Script**

```
function getData() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR-ID").getSheets()[0].getRange("B2").getValue();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a really simple way to accomplish this task:

#### Change the word `edit` to `preview` in the Google Sheets URL, and you'll be able to copy the data from that table.

You can do it like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DLeK4X4MFbQe6X6lcbE_O-rTdy3MHApZEu1HhUWIji4/preview#gid=0

Proof?

```
I can't copy this?
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - i think this was the easiest solution.

To be cleawr . you replace /edit with /preview...

Comment: that's correct, the "preview" makes the magic happen

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue.

I have an iPad and was able to open the locked document using the Google Sheets app. From there, I was able to copy and paste the text to another spreadsheet (in my case, Numbers).